# Google Maps API Android - Tile provider's tiles resolution

Tags: android, google-maps, resolution, tile

I'm using custom TileProviders in my Android app to display offline maps and OpenStreetMap maps. It works, but there is a problem with the tiles resolution, which is quite bad. The files have a size of 256x256, and setting the width/height of my TileProvider to 128 doesn't change anything.

Here is some piece of code :

```
public class GenericUrlTileProvider extends UrlTileProvider {

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Private attributes :

    private String _baseUrl;
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Constructor :
    public GenericUrlTileProvider(int width, int height, String url) {

        super(width, height);

        this._baseUrl = url;
    }

    @Override
    public URL getTileUrl(int x, int y, int zoom) {

        try {
            return new URL(_baseUrl.replace("{z}", "" + zoom).replace("{x}", "" + x).replace("{y}", "" + y));
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

        return null;
    }
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this to support high resolution devices ?

Thanks

Comment: Any solutions on this issue? Stumbled with the same problem.

Comment: No easy solution, the only one I found was to merge the 4 tiles of the next zoom level and return it, but it implies a big performance loss :/ . Please feel free to star the feature request at these pages :
https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6097&q=apitype%3AAndroid2%20type%3AEnhancement&sort=-stars&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Internal%20Stars and https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6982&can=1&q=pixellised&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Stars%20ApiType%20Internal

Comment: Tanks! Will it be brazenly ask to share some code about how are you doing this merging? Not really understand this process :/

Comment: You can see my answer. Not a good solution, but the only one I can see while Google does not support it. You can also abandon Google Maps API and try another API that support high resolution devices, like MapBox.

Answer (score 3):

On @grub request, here is what I did for getting the 4 tiles of the next zoom level :

```
public Tile getTileFromNextZoomLevel(int x, int y, int zoom) {

    final String topLeftTileUrl = _source.getUrlSchema().replace("{z}", "" + (zoom + 1)).replace("{x}", "" + (x * 2)).replace("{y}", "" + (y * 2));
    final String topRightTileUrl = _source.getUrlSchema().replace("{z}", "" + (zoom + 1)).replace("{x}", "" + (x * 2 + 1)).replace("{y}", "" + (y * 2));
    final String bottomLeftTileUrl = _source.getUrlSchema().replace("{z}", "" + (zoom + 1)).replace("{x}", "" + (x * 2)).replace("{y}", "" + (y * 2 + 1));
    final String bottomRightTileUrl = _source.getUrlSchema().replace("{z}", "" + (zoom + 1)).replace("{x}", "" + (x * 2 + 1)).replace("{y}", "" + (y * 2 + 1));

    final Bitmap[] tiles = new Bitmap[4];

    Thread t1 = new Thread() {

        @Override
        public void run() { tiles[0] = Utils.getBitmapFromURL(topLeftTileUrl); }
    };
    t1.start();

    Thread t2 = new Thread() {

        @Override
        public void run() { tiles[1] = Utils.getBitmapFromURL(topRightTileUrl); }
    };
    t2.start();

    Thread t3 = new Thread() {

        @Override
        public void run() { tiles[2] = Utils.getBitmapFromURL(bottomLeftTileUrl); }
    };
    t3.start();

    Thread t4 = new Thread() {

        @Override
        public void run() { tiles[3] = Utils.getBitmapFromURL(bottomRightTileUrl); }
    };
    t4.start();

    try {
        t1.join();
        t2.join();
        t3.join();
        t4.join();
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

    byte[] tile = Utils.mergeBitmaps(tiles, Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG); // PNG is a lot slower, use it only if you really need to

    return tile == null ? TileProvider.NO_TILE : new Tile( (int) _source.getTileSize().getWidth(), (int) _source.getTileSize().getHeight(), tile);
}
```

And the Utils methods :

```
public static byte[] mergeBitmaps(Bitmap[] parts, Bitmap.CompressFormat format) {

    // Check if all the bitmap are null (if so return null) :
    boolean allNulls = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {

        if(parts[i] != null) {

            allNulls = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(allNulls) return null;

    Bitmap tileBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(512, 512, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(tileBitmap);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {

        if(parts[i] == null) {

            parts[i] = Bitmap.createBitmap(256, 256, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        }
        canvas.drawBitmap(parts[i], parts[i].getWidth() * (i % 2), parts[i].getHeight() * (i / 2), paint);
    }

    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    tileBitmap.compress(format, 100, stream);
    byte[] bytes = stream.toByteArray();

    return bytes;
}

public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String urlString) {

    try {

        // Ensure the file exists :
        if(Utils.getResponseCode(urlString) != 200) return null;

        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(connection.getInputStream());

        return bitmap;
    }
    catch (IOException e) { return null; }
}
```

You may have to adapt it for your needs. Please note that my app is still under development, and this code may need some tests / improvements.

Comment: Thank you! Will try it. I hope will have the opportunity to buy you a beer :)